# Do all arrays in C++ classes have to be dynamically allocated, or just their member variables?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, new-operator, conways-game-of-life

For an assignment, I had to separate some code for Conway's Game of Life into multiple files, but now I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of why the code was written the way it was.  I have a class, `World`, and part of the constructor for that class looks like this:

world.h:

```
class World {
public:
    // Constructor/destructor
    World();
    ~World();
    
    void updateWorld();

    ...

private:    
    char **m_grid_1;
    char **m_grid_2;

    ...
};
```

world.cpp:

```
World::World()
{
    m_toggle = true;

    m_grid_1 = new char*[MAX_ROWS];
    m_grid_2 = new char*[MAX_ROWS];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        m_grid_1[i] = new char[MAX_COLS];
        m_grid_2[i] = new char[MAX_COLS];
    }

    ...
}
```

`MAX_ROWS` and `MAX_COLS` are globals that live in a header now.

Arrays have always kind of confused me, so these questions might seem kind of basic:

1. What does char** mean in the context of the member variable `m_grid_1` or `m_grid_2`?  Pointer to a pointer of `char`s?  Those members are 2D arrays, so I'm not sure why pointers are used here instead.
2. Why is `new` used here in combination with that loop in the constructor?  Couldn't you just say `m_grid_1[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];`?

Also, rather than toggle between the two grids, if I wanted to make a local copy of `m_grid_1` in the member function `updateWorld()` and use that local copy to get the next state of the game, would I need to use `new`?  This is what I have now, and it seems to work, but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong by not dynamically allocating the 2D array here:

```
void World::updateWorld() {
    char grid_copy[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLS; j++) {
            grid_copy[i][j] = m_grid_1[i][j];
        }
    }
  
  // loop over grid_copy to find next state of m_grid_1
  
}
```

Comment: The code itself is not good. The code uses c-style arrays in a c++ environment. Try to get a better understanding how to create static c-style arrays and the difference to dynamic arrays. Then you will learn why you need the pointers and why your approach does not work

Comment: This might help [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new). Its a long way from that q&a to understand why the arrays need to be dynamically allocated or not, though thats covered in the answer you got

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I didn't write the main part of this code, I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: @dylosaur yes that is ok, I wanted to say that the code itself is not good and I hope it would not pass a code review if there is no other restriction

Answer (score 3):

> Do all arrays in C++ classes have to be dynamically allocated?

Not in general.

> or just their member variables?

Member variables don't have to be allocated dynamically either.

> 1. What does char** mean ... Pointer to a pointer of chars?

It is a pointer to pointer to char.

> Those members are 2D arrays

Correction: Those members are pointers. They used pointers, therefore they are not arrays.

> 2. Why is new used here in combination with that loop in the constructor?

Because the author of the program chose to use it.

> Couldn't you just say m_grid_1[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];?

Maybe. If `MAX_ROWS` and `MAX_COLS` are compile time constant and if they are small, then sure.

> If I wanted to make a local copy of m_grid_1 in the member function updateWorld() and use that local copy to get the next state of the game, would I need to use new?

If the question is whether you need dynamic allocation, then maybe. See the answer above.

There is hardly ever need to use `new`. A simpler and safer way to create a dynamic array is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and answers every aspect of the question. But I think the answer will not help the user because he is missing basic concepts of c/c++ programming

Comment: `std::array` is also a good candidate because sizes are known at compile-time. The question is just: how big would be the resulting arrays? If small enough, as you said, it's fine not to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: @eerorika The constants are hard-coded, which is part of why I was confused about the dynamic allocation.  MAX_ROWS and MAX_COLS are just 20 in the example, but I could change them to anything.  Would dynamic allocation be better for larger sized grids?  Also, I like vectors, but this was just part of the assignment and I wanted to try to match it closely and learn about why it was written the way it was.